# Shapechanged into an intellect devourer

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, polymorph

If I use *shapechange* and turn into an intellect devourer and then use Body Thief to possess a humanoid, will I be forced out when the spell ends or remain in control of the humanoid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no specific rule to cover it. Once **[Shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange)** ends, the target ceases to be an *[Intellect Devourer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/intellect-devourer)* and loses the **Body Thief** ability. A character can't take advantage of an ability it no longer has, so it's only reasonable to assume it ends.

How that affects for the occupied body, well... I'll leave that visual to each reader's imagination. The body is dead, though, because **Body Thief** says:

> The body then dies, unless its brain is restored within 1 round.

Comment: Blows the mind...

Comment: @Slagmoth Nah, the mind generally has to be gone via **Devour Intellect** before **Body Thief** will work. The skull on the other hand... ;)

Comment: I imagine the body's friends will be quite surprised when that happens...

Comment: *A character can't take advantage of an ability it no longer has, so it's only reasonable to assume it ends.* I don't follow that logic. If my wizard uses the last spell slot on a concentration spell he doesn't immediately lose concentration just because he doesn't have the ability to do it again. The ability should stay active until it runs out or is otherwise disabled.

Comment: @Nwp It's not the same thing. Your caster still has the "spellcasting" ability. You're using a very broad definition of "ability".

Comment: @nwp The character no longer has the ability, _because_ the spell ended; the ability is one that the Intellect Devourer has & the character no longer has the form & abilities of an Intellect Devourer once the spell ends. To compare to your example, if your wizard became something that is no longer a spellcaster, it would lose concentration on spells.